# package clashes with class of same name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день. я пытаюсь отпраить http post с данными(String, Image)

```
     class NewShop extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.addHeader("TOKEN", authToken);

            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            mpEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody(title));
            mpEntity.addPart("address", new StringBody(address));
            mpEntity.addPart("phone_number", new StringBody(phone));
            mpEntity.addPart("description", new StringBody(description));
            mpEntity.addPart("latitude", new StringBody(String.valueOf(lat)));
            mpEntity.addPart("longitude", new StringBody(String.valueOf(lng)));

            File coverFile = new File(picturePath);
            mpEntity.addPart("cover", new FileBody(coverFile, "image/jpeg"));

            File logoFile = new File(logoPath);
            mpEntity.addPart("logo", new FileBody(logoFile, "image/png"));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, mpEntity.toString());

            httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute((HttpUriRequest) httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString((org.apache.http.HttpEntity) resEntity);
            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(responseString);
            Log.d("RESPONSE", j.toString());

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

}
```

выходит сообщение об ошибке:

```
Error:(150, 43) error: cannot access ContentType class file for org.apache.http.entity.ContentType not found
```

Ок. это решается добавлением httpcore библиотеки, но возникает другая проблема.

```
Error:(4, 1) error: package clashes with class of same name
```

поиски по просторам интернета меня ни к чему не привели. Так вот может кто-нибудь обьяснить что это такое?
P.S: используется Android Studio IDE.